# Javascript / Chrome - How to copy an object from the webkit inspector as code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, webkit

I am doing a console.log statement in my javascript in order to log a javascript object. I'm wondering if there's a way, once that's done - to copy that object as javascript code. What I'm trying to do is convert an object that was created using ajax to parse an xml feed into a static javascript object so that a file can run locally, without a server. I've included a screenshot of the object in the chrome inspector window so you can see what I'm trying to do.[image]

Comment: Try using firefox and the option .toSource(). It's easier

Answer (score 1617, accepted):

1. Right-click an object in Chrome's console and select `Store as Global Variable` from the context menu. It will return something like `temp1` as the variable name.
2. Chrome also has a `copy()` method, so `copy(temp1)` in the console should copy that object to your clipboard.

**Note on Recursive Objects:** If you're trying to copy a recursive object, you will get `[object Object]`. The way out is to try `copy(JSON.stringify(temp1))` , the object will be fully copied to your clipboard as a valid JSON, so you'd be able to format it as you wish, using one of many resources.

If you get the `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` message, you can use `JSON.stringify`'s second argument (which is a filter function) to filter out the offending circular properties. See this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659424/622287) for more details.

Comment: return undefined in chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit) ? why >?

Comment: @PardeepJain - that is expected from the copy() method because there is nothing to return. The data should be in your clipboard.

Comment: This just gives `[object Object]` for me.

Comment: @Ullallulloo try logging out with JSON.stringify like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4293047/622287

Comment: Works!  Unfortunately, it seems to give the most recent version of that object at script endtime, not at the time of console.info.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger in that case, I'd try logging it out as `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` instead

Comment: @kevnk: Yeap, that worked, thanks!  Exactly what I did --> function logObject(object) { console.info(JSON.stringify(object).replace(/,/g, ",\n")); }

Comment: Get message `Failed to save to temp variable.`

Comment: @ToniLeigh What browser version are you using? This is still working for me on Chrome 62.0.3202.94

Comment: Doesn't work using version 64.0.3282.140, any other way to get your hands on this without using the `Store as global variable` option?

Comment: it works only if you have a shallow JS object, if you have recursive deep object then will you ll get [Object Object] - that is expected

Comment: What about the {"a":1} at the end? What is that?

Comment: @d-b that was me pasting the results. Sorry if that was confusing.

Comment: option doesnt exist in chrome 74

Comment: @SuperUberDuper - I'm on v75 and the "Store as Global Variable" option exists for objects and arrays...

Comment: @kevnk it works for recursive when used as console.log(JSON.stringify(tepm1))

Comment: Thanks! But how to remove it from global variables? Now every time it pops up in the console.

Comment: Worked fine with three depth levels: `{50: {'20-10-19': {amount: 5, info: {'id': 'test'}}}}`

Comment: Unfortunutely when I right click the object on google chrome, `Store as global variable` option does not show up.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was simple but unknown to me

Comment: The recursive issue was the cause for me to get `[object Object]`! Saved my day. That's definitely not an useful message to understand what's going on.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` can't handle circular references: `Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: @Jacob - Thanks! I've updated the answer. See this other overflow answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12659424/622287

Comment: Does not work with the window object, I get "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Answer (score 75):

In Chrome 89 or later you can simply right click an object in the console and choose `Copy Object` ([ref](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-89/#copy-object)). This also works in some other places inside Chrome Developer Tools e.g. whilst debugging or inside response tab for a network request.

Other option is to use the [`copy`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/#copy-function) command as-is:

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2 };
copy(x);
```

---

[Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10305408/1)

Comment: I don't see how that would work unless you modify the code that logs it.

Comment: I get `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Answer (score 45):

You can copy an object to your clip board using **copy(JSON.stringify(Object_Name));** in the console.

Eg:- Copy & Paste the below code in your console and press ENTER. Now, try to paste(CTRL+V for Windows or CMD+V for mac) it some where else and you will get  *{"name":"Daniel","age":25}*

```
var profile = {
    name: "Daniel",
    age: 25
};

copy(JSON.stringify(profile));
```

Comment: Doesn't work with DOM nodes, window or any other object that it's circular

Comment: By far the easiest solution for a large but simple object.

Comment: easiest  solution

Answer (score 26):

You can now accomplish this in Chrome by right clicking on the object and selecting "Store as Global Variable": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qALFiTlVWdg

[image]

Comment: As of Version 39.0.2171.95, the "Store as Global Variable" option is not available when inspecting Android devices with Chrome.

Comment: @David Calhoun, I voted for your answer.  It looks like your answer was posted June 12, 2014 and the one accepted was Aug 5, 2014, largely taking exactly what you had.  I have to admit that he mentions temp1 where your answer only shows it in your video, so maybe that's why the other answer was accepted.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 13):

If you've sent the object over a request you can copy it from the Chrome -> Network tab.

Request Payload - > View Source

[image]

[image]

Comment: After copying parsed payload, you can format json from https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Answer (score 13):

Follow the following steps:

1. Output the object with console.log from your code, like so: console.log(myObject)
2. Right click on the object and click "Store as Global Object". Chrome would print the name of the variable at this point. Let's assume it's called "temp1".
3. In the console, type: `JSON.stringify(temp1)`.
4. At this point you will see the entire JSON object as a string that you can copy/paste.
5. You can use online tools like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to prettify your string at this point.

Comment: Step with JSON.stringify(temp1) could affect to a long time execution if object is big.

Comment: @JoeTidee I had the same issue, but I set up a `debugger` statement and then retrieved my var directly from the console at the breakpoint.

Answer (score 6):

### Update - Chrome 89

Right click -> Copy object

source: (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2021/01/devtools?utm_source=devtools)

[image]

> also from debugger

[image]

Comment: Do you know a way to keep properties that are `undefined`?

Comment: amm It's really not a solve one issue, but you can do manipulation to have the key and value if you have `Object.entries({test: undefined, test2: 2}).map(([key,value])=>({key,value}))` and after copy you will get `[
    {
        "key": "test"
    },
    {
        "key": "test2",
        "value": 2
    }
]`

Comment: People, can you just STOP posting those invalid answers already? Using the `copy()` function on an object only EVER results in the exact string `[object Object]` being copied. It's useless!

Answer (score 4):

This actually helped me out mine is a bit of an edge case. But for what I am doing it works.

The devices I am testing on use safari debug tools and I can never copy the objects like you can in Chrome simply right click and copy object.

Tried JSON.stringify and the pasting the contents into https://beautifier.io but then have to try reformat it.

I ended up using local storage and the copy method.

In your code use.

```
localStorage.setItem('dataCopy', JSON.stringify(data));
```

Then just paste this in the console and click enter.

```
copy(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.dataCopy))
```

You then have your array of objects in the clip board.

Answer (score 1):

This should help stringify deep objects by leaving out recursive `Window` and `Node` objects.

```
function stringifyObject(e) {
  const obj = {};
  for (let k in e) {
    obj[k] = e[k];
  }

  return JSON.stringify(obj, (k, v) => {
    if (v instanceof Node) return 'Node';
    if (v instanceof Window) return 'Window';
    return v;
  }, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Does not work: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Window'

Answer (score 1):

you can console the object as string

```
var objToString = JSON.stringify(obj)
console.log(objToString );
```

Then in an editor like Notepad ++ paste de output and then ehit a plugin format

[JSFormat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vXxp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Using "Store as a Global Variable" works, but it only gets the final instance of the object, and not the moment the object is being logged (since you're likely wanting to compare changes to the object as they happen).  To get the object at its exact point in time of being modified, I use this...

```
function logObject(object) {
    console.info(JSON.stringify(object).replace(/,/g, ",\n"));
}
```

Call it like so...

```
logObject(puzzle);
```

You may want to remove the .replace(/./g, ",\n") regex if your data happens to have comma's in it.

Answer (score 0):

So,. I had this issue,. except I got [object object]

I'm sure you could do this with recursion but this worked for me:

Here is what I did in my console:

```
var object_that_is_not_shallow = $("all_obects_with_this_class_name");
var str = '';
object_that_is_not_shallow.map(function(_,e){
    str += $(e).html();
});
copy(str);
```

Then paste into your editor.

Answer (score 0):

[Right click on data which you want to store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHxap.png)

- Firstly, Right click on data which you want to store -> select "Store as global variable"
  And the new temp variable appear like bellow: (temp3 variable):
  [New temp variable appear in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i60Ge.png)
- Second use command copy(temp_variable_name) like picture:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3Zh.png)
  After that, you can paste data to anywhere you want.
  hope useful/

Answer (score 0):

If you have `bigint` data in JSON, all the answers do not work.

When you try to serialize an object that contains `bigint` values using `JSON.stringify()`, it throws a TypeError because it doesn't know how to represent `bigint` values as strings.

You need a usage code:

```js
copy(JSON.stringify(temp1, (_, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : v))
```

This function `(_, v) => typeof v === 'bigint' ? v.toString() : v)` checks if the value is of type `bigint`. If so, it converts the value to a string using `toString()`. Otherwise, it leaves the value unchanged. This way, you can serialize objects containing `bigint` values without encountering errors.

[Screenshot copy bigint from chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs491.png)

Comment: Hey, thanks for pitching in on StackOverflow! Your answer seems a bit unclear and might leave readers scratching their heads. Could you provide more context or clarify your points to make it easier to follow? Feel free to [edit] your answer for better clarity and understanding.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your console and execute

```
copy(JSON.stringify(foo));
```

This copies your JSON to clipboard

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON