# Store objects in localStorage that can't be json stringify'd?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with multiple circular references that I would like to keep in localStorage. Since localStorage only stores key/value pairs and converts everything to a string, is there a way for me to store this object locally?

Comment: Perhaps modify your JSON a little bit so that instead of having a circular reference make it have some kind of identifier reference to the already existing object. If you post your actual problem I might help with your solution.

Comment: maybe indexedDB? not sure if it will work for this, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answers to [Stringify javascript object with circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference).  If you can't find a replacement for JSON.stringify, you can write your own `replacer` function to handle the circular references.

See MDN ([Using native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON)) and MSDN ([JSON.stringify Function (JavaScript)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)) documentation for more information.