# Json.stringfy not convert a advanced object, but it does work with a simple object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, razor, model

I am working with mvc 4 and jQuery. If I try it this works

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Raj";
obj.age  = 32;
obj.married = false;
var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(jsonString);
```

But if I try to convert to my object to JSON it does not work

```
var obj = new Object();
obj.name = "Raj";
obj.age  = 32;
obj.married = false;
obj.Venta=@Model;
var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);
alert(jsonString);
```

As you see I added @Model then this does not work.

I need convert this object to JSON and this would be great if there is a automatic way for get it

```
public class VentaProd
{
    public IEnumerable<product> ListadoProductos {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<account> ListadoClientes { get; set; }
    public sale Venta { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: *"as you see i added @Model then this does not work"* You don't show us the output, so no, we cannot see that it does not work.

Comment: Does that throw circular reference error or what?

Comment: when i add @Model there is not a output, if i dont added this does have a output

Comment: @angel But is there any error in console?

Comment: How can i get this possible error? sorry

Comment: [Learn how to debug JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging).

Comment: in that code when I add @Model  the line alert(jsonString);  never is executed

Comment: with a try catch i got tihs error  ejercicio1 is not defined and my model is @model ejercicio1.Models.ClasesCombinadas.VentaProd  but this line does work  obj.Venta=@Model.Venta.id;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, C# Models/variables should be enclosed within quotes when assigned to java script variables.

Try doing:
obj.Venta = '@Model';

Hope this helps!

Comment: this runs but this prints the type of model,  "ejercicio1.Models.ClasesCombinadas.VentaProd"

Comment: I never came accorss this scenario but logically its worth a try. If your Model is VentaProd then I think the code should look like this:             obj.Venta = '@Model.Venta';

Comment: yes my Model is VentaProd then how the controller must to read it? as a string?

Comment: really which i want to do is convert to json my object for read it on controller the real code would be obj='@Model' and i got \" ejercicio1.Models.ClasesCombinadas.VentaProd\" now i am not sure if i could deserializate it using JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: Well converting C# object to JSON using razor can be done like this:                                    var obj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));

Comment: i believe this  could work but now i got a circular reference

Comment: Here is very nice answer with example to solve circular reference problem. Assuming you are getting it in JSON.Stringify method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference