# Accessing circular JSON structure

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am accessing a module from the node.js 's require cache. But it is returning a circular JSON structure. I want to access the **exports** property of the module. Please help :

```
   var moduleDef = require.cache[moduleName];
   console.log(moduleDef)         // Prints fine
   console.log(moduleDef.exports) // returns undefined
```

Comment: try `console.log(util.inspect(moduleDef.exports))`

Answer (score 1):

[Already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference)

```
JSON.stringify(moduleDef.exports, function( key, value) {
  if(key == 'moduleName') { 
    return value.id;
  } else {
    return value;
  };
})
```