# Taming hasMany/belongsToOne circular reference in client side ORM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, orm, circular-reference

I'm using angular in my case but it's a general question as well. Also I'm aware of other front end ORM solutions like js-data and restacular but that's a different story.

Given a `People` collection made of several `Person` instances:

```
[
    { name: "Bob" },
    { name: "Dave" },
    { name: "Sarah" }
]
```

How can each `Person` instance have the ability (method) to push a new instance of itself with inherited properties into its parent collection? Let's say a `Person` instance looks like this:

```
{
    name: "Bob",
    parent: [ /* circular reference to collection */ ],
    extend: function(attrs) { /* returns new object */ },
    create: function(attrs) {
        var self = this;
        //call factory method to create object
        var person = self.extend(attrs);
        //some http call to persist to backend
        .then(function() {
            //push new instance to parent so it's rendered in the view model
            self.parent.push(person);
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe this method of encapsulation is bad...I'm not sure. I made [a plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/e91ebmY6a2D3Qiat6PjQ?p=preview) that attempts to create a directive that inherits a JSON stringified circular reference (not good) via two way binding.

**directive**

```
angular
    .module("app", [])
    .directive("appDirective", function() {
        return {
            scope: { data: "=appDirective" },
            bindToController: true,
            controllerAs: "vm"
        };
    });
```

**html**

```
<div app-directive="{foo: 'bar', info: vm.info}">{{vm.data}}</div>
```

**inside parent controller**

```
this.info = {};
//setup circular reference
this.info.info = this.info
```

How can I retain the luxury of circular references in my ORM while getting around the circular JSON stringify problem?

Comment: You'll need to write your own stringify, pulling out the objects to a reference array and replacing them with the reference array key.  Or you can use the [jsog](https://github.com/jsog/jsog) library that I have found useful

Comment: also, [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference/12659424#12659424) if you are interested in trying to do it yourself

Comment: glad it helped.  Seems like something that should have been taken into account in core javascript (or at least angular), but it is what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write your own stringify, pulling out the objects to a reference array and replacing them with the reference array key. Or you can use the [jsog](https://github.com/jsog/jsog) library that I have found useful

also, this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-javascript-object-with-circular-reference/12659424#12659424) answer if you are interested in trying to do it yourself