# Overwrite the JSON.stringify in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a function that returns an object tree structure. But this tree structure contains a circular reference. (Note: I need this circularity in my data model, So I can't change it). I attached this object to the scope like this:

```
$scope.tree = myService.getTree(); //This return the circular structure
```

Then I tried to display this in my html file like this:

```
{{tree}}
```

But when I try to do this, it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

I know when I call {{tree}} in my html file, angularjs is calling JSON.stringify(tree) for me. My question is, how do I overwrite the behaviour on JSON.stringify in angular. For example can I tell angular or JSON.stringify to stop serialising the object tree if it detects a circularity in the object tree and return the json string it generated so far (instead of trowing an error).

Or alternatively, can I overwrite the behaviour to not call JSON.stringify for the whole object and instead call JSON.stringify or JSON.toString for individual objects inside the object tree as I access them.
For example, if I call:

```
{{tree.person.name}}
```

then angular will only call stringify on the tree object and person object.

Comment: Should read the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$scope.tree = JSON.parse(myService.getTree())
```