# Handling TypeError: cyclic object value in Angular 2 Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I am trying get data from a service function , which gets some data from another function in the same service.

I am calling service function in **component** like this :-

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
   ngOnInit() {

        this.dataService.getDDs().subscribe(
             data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data))},
             error => console.log(error)
         );

    }
}
```

**first function** in service

```
getDefaults(){

    return this._http.get('url')
        .map((result: Response) => {
          const res = result.json();

          return res;
        }, err => {
              console.log(err);
        });

  }
```

**second function** in service

```
getDDs(){

    return this._http.get('url')
    .map((result: Response) => {
      const data = result.json();

           return this.getDefaults().subscribe(
             datab => {
                         if (data.length !== 0) {

                            //some operation on datab
                            return datab; //this should return in component

                          }else{
                            return datab; //this should return in component
                          }
                      },
            error => console.log(error)
            );

    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

}
```

On running , it throws error **TypeError: cyclic object value**

Any better way to do this ? second function depends on first function.

Comment: Does the error go away if you change `data => {console.log(JSON.stringify(data))},` to `data => {console.log(JSON.stringify({a: 'b'}))},`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes it does not throw error now. how can i solve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference

Comment: Remove JSON.Stringify in your console.log and try.

Comment: I am trying to implement that solution , but for that i dont what key is causing cyclic reference. yes when i remove JSON.Stringify it works.