# Converting an object Promise to string

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

sorry my english!
Is there a way to get the value of the storage saved object? What I mean is when I output it in the console it shows `[object Promise]` but when I output in an alert it shows the string value. Is there a way to save that string value in the storage?

This is my code:

```js
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();

    FCMPlugin.getToken(
      (token) => {
        this.saveToken(token);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    this.onNotification();
  });
}

saveToken(token: string) {
  this.storage.set('token', token);
}
```

This is the plugin code which returns the token

```js
// GET TOKEN //
else if (action.equals("getToken")) {
  cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
          String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
          callbackContext.success(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
          Log.d(TAG, "\tToken: " + token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "\tError retrieving token");
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: I think that the function `JSON.stringify( nameOfSomeObject );` might help you. If there are any circular structures, then you might have to check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference.

Comment: this.storage.get('token')

Comment: Where is the point in your code that you are outputting the token to the console?