# Why do some arrays appear with letters next to the value in chrome inspector?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I am using chrome browser inspector to examine some javascript arrays. I notice that certain arrays (that are being generated by a library that I am using - `three.js` via `a-frame`) are represented with lowercase letters next to the value.

Please see below an example - you can see the lower case cs that accompany each value;

[image]

And here is one that I have generated myself for comparison - rather than these cs there is a generic object representation. This is what I am accustomed to;

[image]

Why do those letters appear? What is the difference between these arrays?

I ask because 1. I am curious and 2. I am seeing different behaviour between these 2 types of array and am wondering whether this is an indication of a different format that I am not aware of.

If there is a difference that people are aware of, I wonder whether its possible to convert one to the other quickly? So that I can eliminate that as a reason for any bugs?

Thanks as ever for any advice, If you need more information to answer, please let me know.

Comment: The c is because they are instances of a "class" and the ones that show the literal are plain objects.

Comment: Thank you Juan, do you know if there is a way to convert those to plain objects? As I say I am experiencing some differences in behaviour and I would like to rule that difference out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))` on both arrays to convert everything to plain arrays with plain objects.

The only thing to care is that objects don't have [circular references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference) but from what I can see yours don't.

Comment: Perfect - thank you so much smnbbrv, it all now works as I would expect, I thought that might be causing the problem. Much appreciated.