# How can I reformat this simple JSON so it doesn't catch "Circular structure to JSON" exception?

Tags: javascript, json

**Introduction**

I'm learning JavaScript on my own and JSON its something along the path. I'm working on a JavaScript WebScraper and I want, for now, load my results in JSON format.

I know I can use data base, server-client stuff, etc to work with data. But I want to take this approach as learning JSON and how to parse/create/format it's my main goal for today.

**Explaining variables**

As you may have guessed the data stored in the fore mentioned variables comes from an html file. So an example of the content in:

```
users[] -> "<a href=\"countries.php?id=1\">Egypt</a>"
GDP[] -> "<td> $2,971</td>"
Regions[] -> "<td> Egypt </td>"
Align[] -> "<td> Eastern Bloc </td>"
```

**Code**

```
let countries = [];
for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
    countries.push( {
        'country' : [{
            'name' : users[i],
            'GDP' : GDP[i],
            'Region' : regions[i],
            'Align' : align[i]

    }]})
};



let obj_data = JSON.stringify(countries, null, 2);
fs.writeFileSync('countryballs.json', obj_data);
```

**Code explanation**

I have previously loaded into arrays `(users, GDP, regionsm align)` those store the data `(String format)` I had extracted from a website.

My idea was to then "dump" it into an object with which the `stringify()` function format would format it into JSON.

I have tested it without the loop (static data just for testing) and it works.

**Type of error**

```
let obj_data = JSON.stringify(countries, null, 2);
                        ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Node'
    |     property 'children' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Node'
    --- property 'parent' closes the circle
```

**What I want from this question**

I want to know what makes this JSON format "Circular" and how to make this code work for my goals.

**Notes**

- I am working with Node.js and Visual Studio Code

**EDIT**

This is further explanation for those who were interested and thought it was not a good question.

**Test code that works**

```
let countries;
    console.log(users.length)
    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    {
        countries = {
            
            country : [
                {
                    "name" : 'CountryTest'
                }
            ]
        } 
            
    };
     
    let obj_data = JSON.stringify(countries, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('countryballs.json', obj_data);    
});
```

Notice in comparison to the previous code, right now I am inputing "manually" the name of the country object.

This way absolutely works  as you can see below:

[image: Image of the result]

Now, if I change `'CountryTest'` to into a `users[i]` where I store country names (Forget about why countries are tagged users, it is out of the scope of this question)

It shows me the previous circular error.

A "Partial Solution" for this was to add `+""` which, as I said, partially solved the problem as now there is not "Circular Error"

**Example:**

```
 for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
    {
        countries = {
            
            country : [
                {
                    "name" : users[i]+''
                }
            ]
        }   
    };
```

Resulting in:

[image: Stop downvoting without telling why... those who are learning need feedback to improve]

**Another bug, which I do not know why is that only shows 1 country when there are 32 in the array users[]**

This makes me think that the answers provided are not correct so far.

**Desired JSON format**

```
{
  "countries": {
    "country": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "GDP" : "",
        "Region" : "",
        "Align" : ""
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "GDP" : "",
        "Region" : "",
        "Align" : ""
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "GDP" : "",
        "Region" : "",
        "Align" : ""
      }
      
    ]}
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `users`, `GDP`, `regions`, and `align`?

Comment: Checkout these links, **https://javascript.info/json**  **https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON**

Comment: Not exactly related, but the data structure seems to contain an extra array. It would be simpler to use the data, if `country` would be a simple object instead of an array containing the actual data object.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://jsbin.com/wicepavame/edit?js,console), so you are not showing everything here.

Comment: @VLAZ I updated the question with the exception error

Comment: @WhiteGlove but not with the data you used to create that object. It seems like you somehow have the same array inside itself or something along those lines.

Comment: @VLAZ Last edit for today, hope you understand and be able to help me. Thanks

Comment: If `+ ""` is a functional workaround, this implies that `users` does not consist of primitives but objects. So those could be referring to themselves somehow. Without knowing *what* those are, it's hard to say but when you do `+ ""` you are forcing a conversion to a primitive string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EUREKA!**

As some of you have mentioned above, let me tell you **it is not a problem of circularity**, at first..., in the JSON design. It is an error of the data itself.

When I **scraped** the data it came in html format i.e `<td>whatever</td>`, I did not care about that as I could simply take it away later. I was way too focused in having the JSON well formatted and learning.

As `@VLAZ` and `@Scott Sauyezt` mentioned above, it could be that some of the data, if it is not well formatted into string, it might be referring to itself somehow as so I started to work on that.

**Lets have a look at this assumption...**

To extract the data I used the `cheerio.js` which gives you a kind of jquery thing to parse html.

To extract the name of the country I used:

```
nullTest = ($('table').eq(2).find('tr').eq(i).find('td').find('a').last());
            //"Partial solution" for the OutOfIndex nulls
            if (nullTest != null)
            {
                users.push(nullTest);                
            }
```

*(nullTest helps me avoid nulls, I will implement some RegEx when everything works to polish the code a bit)*

This "query" would output me something like:

```
<a href="source">whatEverIsInHereIfThereIsAny</a>
```

or else.

to get rid off this html thing just add .html() at the end of the "jquery" such as:

```
($('table').eq(2).find('tr').eq(i).find('td').find('a').last().html());
```

That way you are now working with String and avoiding any error and thus solves this question.

Answer (score 1):

Circular structure error occurs when you have a property of the object which is the object itself directly (a -> a) or indirectly (a -> b -> a).

To avoid the error message, tell JSON.stringify what to do when it encounters a circular reference. For example, if you have a person pointing to another person ("parent"), which may (or may not) point to the original person, do the following:

```
JSON.stringify( that.person, function( key, value) {
  if( key == 'parent') { return value.id;}
  else {return value;}
})
```

The second parameter to stringify is a filter function. Here it simply converts the referred object to its ID, but you are free to do whatever you like to break the circular reference.

You can test the above code with the following:

```
function Person( params) {
  this.id = params['id'];
  this.name = params['name']; 
  this.father = null;
  this.fingers = [];
  // etc.
}

var me = new Person({ id: 1, name: 'Luke'});
var him = new Person( { id:2, name: 'Darth Vader'});
me.father = him; 
JSON.stringify(me); // so far so good

him.father = me; // time travel assumed :-)
JSON.stringify(me); // "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
// But this should do the job:
JSON.stringify(me, function( key, value) {
  if(key == 'father') { 
    return value.id;
  } else {
    return value;
  };
})
```

The answer is from StackOverflow question,

[Stringify (convert to JSON) a JavaScript object with circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference)

Comment: Instead of posting the exact answer, you can close the question as a duplicate which will create a link to the existing question (and therefor answer)

Comment: Ok, I will do it for the next time, @MarkC.

Answer (score 1):

From your output, it looks as though `users` is a list of DOM nodes.  Rather than referring to these directly (where there are all sort of possible cyclical structures), if you just want their text, instead of using `users` directly, try something like

```js
country : [
    {
        "name" : users[i].textContent // maybe also followed by `.trim()
    }
]
```

Or you could do this up front to your whole list:

```js
const usersText = [...users].map(node => node.textContent)
```

and then use `usersText` in place of `users` as you build your object.

If `GDP`, `regions` and `align` are also references to your HTML, then you might have to do the same with them.

Comment: Then perhaps they are not DOM nodes.  It simply looked like it from one of your screen shots.

Comment: It would really help if you'd explain what is in `users`, and where it comes from.

Comment: hope it helps the new Edit of Explaining varibales

Comment: @WhiteGlove: I'm afraid that new section is not enough.  What type of data is in `users`?  If it were just strings, then things should work, even if these aren't the exact strings you want.  If they are DOM nodes, I would expect the above answer to work, although I could be mistaken.  If it's something like a jQuery wrapper object, you'll need to use its API.  (It's been a long time, something like `$(users[i]).text()`, perhaps?)  If it's something else, please let us know what it is, and how you create/find it.

Comment: in the CMD when I run node scrap.js. Shows the string in green, idk if that helps

Comment: If `scrap.js` is some screen scraper, then you'll have to check out its documentation.  Many of them are based on [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) or [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom), if that helps.

Comment: nope. scrap.js is made by myself and following tutorials and docs. I kind of solved the main problem but not getting my desired JSON format.

Comment: Glad you solved it.  You clearly put a great deal of effort into writing the question, and it's appreciated.  A gentle hint, though: Next time, try to pay closer attention to what people are asking for in the comments; they are usually a sign of communication breakdown.  If you don't understand a comment, ask for a clarification about it, but think of the comments as helpful people trying to work with you to get to a solution.  A careful answer to the first comment from VLAZ would probably have helped solve this much more quickly.

Comment: Whenever I get a "solution comment" I start working on it to test. If it works I either ask them to post a solution to accept it or I do myself. Thank you all.