# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - Webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, webpack-4

I'm working on an e-commerce project for a client using nextJs. I was trying to optimize images using next-optimized-images. Though it works fine I get the error in terminal. I'm new to webpack and I have configured my next.config based on https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images

**next.config**

```
require('dotenv').config();

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const withOptimizedImages = require('next-optimized-images');

const nextConfig = {
  env: {
    PORT: process.env.PORT,
    REST_URL: process.env.REST_URL,
    GRAPHQL_URL: process.env.GRAPHQL_URL,
    FRONTEND_URL: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
    RAZORPAY_KEY: process.env.RAZORPAY_KEY,
    RAZORPAY_SECRET: process.env.RAZORPAY_SECRET,
    MAGENTO_ADMIN_TOKEN: process.env.MAGENTO_ADMIN_TOKEN,
  },
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [
    [
      withOptimizedImages,
      {
        inlineImageLimit: 8192,
        imagesFolder: 'images',
        imagesName: '[name]-[hash].[ext]',
        handleImages: ['jpeg', 'png', 'svg', 'webp', 'gif'],
        optimizeImages: true,
        optimizeImagesInDev: true,
        mozjpeg: {
          quality: 80,
        },
        optipng: {
          optimizationLevel: 3,
        },
        pngquant: false,
        webp: {
          preset: 'default',
          quality: 75,
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  nextConfig
);
```

[image: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON - Webpack]

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference

Comment: You might need to look at `importing mp4`  files. Something like this should do https://github.com/jeremybarbet/next-videos. Currently  There are no loaders to handle this file and so webpack throws an error.

Comment: @Panther It's not just mp4. I'm getting the same error for scss as well. eg- ./public/styles/modal.scss?size=980. It's not visible in ss.

Comment: @user369142 The error is with the webpack modules. How do I resolve that?