# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON -- Next.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, next.js, typeerror

I'm writing an API in Next.js to insert data into a MySQL database. The error I'm experiencing relates to a circular reference, but I'm having trouble finding it. Please be aware that I am also using Axios to write this API.

I'm running into the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Query'
    |     property '_timer' -> object with constructor 'Timer'
    --- property '_object' closes the circle
```

Here is my API:

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import * as pool from "../../../src/utils/dbConnection";
import console from "console";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { email, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body as any;
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await conn.query(
      `INSERT INTO Users(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`,
      [email, password, firstname, lastname]
    );

    res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(rows));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) conn.end(); // close connection
  }
};
```

Comment: Why do you use `JSON.stringify` in `res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(rows));`? Should be just `res.status(201).json(rows);` I guess (201 for Created).

Comment: Does your database have a `.toArray()` method that will convert `rows` into an actual array?

Comment: Which database module on NPM are you using?

Comment: If `JSON.stringify(rows)` is giving you the circular structure error, then you have to see what `rows` actually is and somehow convert it to a plain array of data that doesn't contain any database stuff in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem is here:  `res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(rows));`. So, from the docs of [`res.json`](https://expressjs.com/de/api.html#res.json):

> Sends a JSON response. This method sends a response (with the correct
> content-type) that is the parameter converted to a JSON string using
> [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Therefore you just need `res.json(rows);` or maybe `res.status(201).json(rows);`, where `201` means [Created](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201).

**Edit:**

I think there might be another problem. The query to insert data does not return the inserted rows (if you use [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql)). So, please log `rows` to check its content - and as mentioned by @jfriend00 there could be and properly are some circular references.

However, you can get the [id of the inserted row](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row) or [the number of affected rows](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#getting-the-number-of-affected-rows) for example.

Comment: But, if `rows` has circular references, that problem will still be an issue.

Comment: In my case, I fed the whole `response` object, which of course will cause the circular problem. Use `.json(response.data)` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import * as pool from "../../../src/utils/dbConnection";
import console from "console";

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { email, password, firstname, lastname } = req.body as any;
  let conn;
  try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
    const rows = await conn.query(
      `INSERT INTO Users(email, password, firstname, lastname) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)`,
      [email, password, firstname, lastname]
    );
    // Error related to your response
    // You should not return in response all function related to your db
    // return rows.rows
    res.status(200).json(rows.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) conn.end(); // close connection
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

I personally use `safe-json-stringify` which has a method to modify objects without stringifying, in case you want a circular-safe object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/safe-json-stringify

```
res.status(200).json(safeJsonStringify.ensureProperties(data));
```

Otherwise, you can look at many other posts on the subject:
[Stringify (convert to JSON) a JavaScript object with circular reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392293/stringify-convert-to-json-a-javascript-object-with-circular-reference)

About natively removing circulars.