# Copy variable from network tab preview in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using the Chrome Dev Tools, and I am digging through the network pane to look at an XHR response with the preview tab.  I want to grab a specific object from the preview.  But when I try to [store as global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305365/javascript-chrome-how-to-copy-an-object-from-the-webkit-inspector-as-code/25140576#25140576) by right clicking preview object, the temp variable created was null.

I find that rather strange since the data is in memory (otherwise it wouldn't be displayed at all).  Here's an example of a rather large response array that I'm trying to get a specific object from.

> [image: Dev Tools]

To clarify, I can store a variable that appears in my console.  But I can't store a variable from the preview pane of the network tab.  Is there any feature of the Chrome Dev Tools I'm overlooking, or am I forced to console log my XHR response and pull the object from there?

I'd really rather not add any `console.log()` or other breakpoints into my code just to have to remove them later.  Digging through the super-long raw JSON response is also not practical.  I'm using Chrome 47 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug in Chrome Dev Tools that is now fixed with the latest version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can get it to work by going:

1. Right click on the array index
2. "Store as global variable"

Then from the console, typing:

```
copy(temp1);
```

And then it will be on the clipboard.

[image]

Comment: Huh, I guess this is finally fixed.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but you could go to response tab, copy the response content and then in the console  just paste it after :

```
var response = <<paste here>>
```

i cant tell by the screenshot but you can then type `response.data[64]`

Comment: This is at least somewhat a workaround.  It's not perfect because the dev tools seems to lag out when handling an object of that massive size, but at least I am able to specify an index and manipulate the individual piece of the giant array.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you're right. Today i've the exact same issue with a response data. I was unable to paste it so i loaded jquery into the console and request the file manually. But this is not the ideal solution :(