# Chrome - save data from network to file?

Tags: json, google-chrome

I have some data in the chrome console. It is a JSON format. I would like to save it on my computer. I have tried to copy-paste, but this is not working. I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49912101/6608257), but it did not work. Any idea of how to do itthis?

Thank in advance.

[image]

Comment: do you get those from network, api or something?

Comment: @CaptainMhmdrz_A Yes, I get those from the network. It a single page application that downloads data in the background. I and would like to access bulk of data.