# Get value that is inside the response array in the Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, console

I'm new to javascript programming and I really need help. I thank everyone for their collaboration and I will always be ready to help too.
My question is how to get information from inside the array response, right on the console?

In the image below I can better show what I need to do.
[Google chrome console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G2Xu.jpg)

Comment: assuming that you make an AJAX you should have access to that data using response.data.<name of the object> i guess you named the array response in your case, so response.data.response.forEach(el => { console.log(el.val)})

Comment: I was unable to retrieve the data the way you indicated !!
My question is similar to this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530967/copy-variable-from-network-tab-preview-in-chrome-dev-tools

I need to be able to display a specified value from the Network / Response tab result on the console. Is it possible to do this through the Google Chrome console?

I already tried something like response.data [3] but it doesn't work, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined".