# Extracting only date from moment object

Tags: ionic-framework, momentjs

I am using ion2 calendar for creating a multidatepicker. Here I am using onSelect event emitter.

```
onSelect($event) {

 console.log("onSelect event called");
 console.log($event);  

};
```

Here when I print '$event' the console output looks like this:

How to extract only date from this moment object in the format 'DD-MMMM-YYYY'?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Below one liner will give you desired output:

```
let formattedDate = moment($event[0].Moment._d).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY');
```

So your function will become

```
onSelect($event) {
    let formattedDate = moment($event[0].Moment._d).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY');
    console.log("onSelect event called");
    console.log($event);  
};
```

**Note** : As I can not debug your code so please check first that if `$event[0].Moment._d` is giving you highlighted date (_d: Wed May 16 ........) in your question.

Comment: Hi VicJordan, Thanks for the response. DD-MMMM-YYYY format is for displaying full name of a month. For ex : 28 August 2014

Comment: @ChaitraR just updated my answer. It will work and print full month name. Check it out.

Comment: I am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot read property '_d' of undefined

Comment: @ChaitraR updated answer. Check with `$event[0].Moment._d`. It should work.

Comment: Now I got this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'Moment' of undefined

Comment: Let me try $event[0].Moment[0]._d

Comment: @ChaitraR can you share `$event` value in JSON format?

Comment: It looks as above.  In question itself I have given the json format.

Comment: @ChaitraR that is screenshot. I can not debug the screenshot data. Give the data so that I can run it locally and solve your problem.

Comment: @ChaitraR if you dont know how to copy data then check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25140576/631803

Comment: I am getting only this line: "2018-05-09T18:30:00.000Z"

Comment: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 1525890600000, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d
:
Thu May 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i
:
1525890600000
_isAMomentObject
:
true
_isUTC
:
false
_isValid
:
true
_locale
:
Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf
:
{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Not sure how I am getting it. When I tried to use copy(temp1) I got that. So I did console.log(temp1) copied the object and pasted here.

Comment: @ChaitraR paste your JSON data here and share the link : http://myjson.com/

Comment: @ChaitraR tell me about this one line? How you are getting this value "2018-05-09T18:30:00.000Z"?

Comment: Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: 1525890600000, _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, _locale: Locale, …}
_d
:
Thu May 10 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) {}
_i
:
1525890600000
_isAMomentObject
:
true
_isUTC
:
false
_isValid
:
true
_locale
:
Locale {_calendar: {…}, _longDateFormat: {…}, _invalidDate: "Invalid date", ordinal: ƒ, _dayOfMonthOrdinalParse: /\d{1,2}(th|st|nd|rd)/, …}
_pf
:
{empty: false, unusedTokens: Array(0), unusedInput: Array(0), overflow: -2, charsLeftOver: 0, …}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: I got the solution. Now I am able to print the extracted date in the console.


  onSelect($event) {
      console.log("onSelect event called");
      console.log(JSON.stringify($event.format('DD-MMMM-YYYY')));
  };

Answer (score 0):

In your case just use `moment($event[0]).format('DD-MMMM-YYYY')`

```js
console.log(moment().format('DD-MMMM-YYYY'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is depreciated

Comment: @Hunt, What is deprecated?