# About JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have string like below:

```
const diaChinh = "{'codeTinh':'HN', 'tinh' : 'Hà Nội' , 'codeHuyen ': 718, 'huyen ': 'Quận Bắc Từ Liêm, Hà Nội'}"
```

How to format it like below:

```
const diaChinh = {codeTinh:'HN', tinh : 'Hà Nội' , codeHuyen: 718, huyen: 'Quận Bắc Từ Liêm, Hà Nội'}
```

Comment: Is this really the way the string is quoted? With single `'` quotes around the properties and values? It's not valid JSON like that.

Comment: Read here to write down your variable contents: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305365/javascript-chrome-how-to-copy-an-object-from-the-webkit-inspector-as-code

Answer (score 2):

First you have to replace `'` inside your JSON with `"`. Then, you have to remove any kind of whitespace(s) present in property strings like in `'codeHuyen ': 718, 'huyen ': 'Quận Bắc Từ Liêm, Hà Nội'`

You can use [JSON.parse](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse_json.asp) method.

```js
var diaChinh = "{'codeTinh':'HN', 'tinh' : 'Hà Nội' , 'codeHuyen ': 718, 'huyen ': 'Quận Bắc Từ Liêm, Hà Nội'}";

diaChinh = diaChinh.replace(/\s+(?='\s*:\s*,*)/g, '');
diaChinh = diaChinh.replace(/\'/g, '"');

var obj = JSON.parse(diaChinh);
console.log(obj.huyen);
```

Comment: Hi @ThủyVũVăn if this (or any other further answers) has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this