# I have an array of objects with varying length based on selected city. How to select the element which hold an object with certain property?

Tags: javascript

Long story short, array's length depends on the selected city so I can't select the element using an index because I can't know what index would the element have. Therefore I somehow need to select it based on the value of one of its properties.

In my case, I want to select the element which contains the object that has property `types: ['locality', 'political']`.

Example results. I haven't included the first 7 array elements since they are not relevent:

```
7:
    address_components: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    types: Array(2)
        0: "locality"
        1: "political"
8:
    address_components: (2) [{…}, {…}]
    types: Array(2)
        0: "administrative_area_level_1"
        1: "political"
```

As you can see, every element has a `types` property which is an array. I'm currently trying to select element with index 7 using the `types: ['locality', 'political']` and not the index.

Sadly I have no clue how to do that so I haven't supplemented any code.

```
[
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "19",
        "short_name": "19",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Clanbrassil Street Lower",
        "short_name": "Clanbrassil Street Lower",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Wood Quay",
        "short_name": "Wood Quay",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "D08 X798",
        "short_name": "D08 X798",
        "types": [
          "postal_code"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "19 Clanbrassil Street Lower, Wood Quay, Dublin, D08 X798, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3349244,
        "lng": -6.2740099
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.3362733802915,
          "lng": -6.272660919708499
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.3335754197085,
          "lng": -6.275358880291503
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJZckoE7wNZ0gRgHdbQYYvYTk",
    "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "8PMG+X9 Dublin, County Dublin, Ireland",
      "global_code": "9C5M8PMG+X9"
    },
    "types": [
      "cafe",
      "establishment",
      "food",
      "point_of_interest"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "21",
        "short_name": "21",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "R137",
        "short_name": "R137",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Wood Quay",
        "short_name": "Wood Quay",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "21 R137, Wood Quay, Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3348735,
        "lng": -6.273865
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.3362224802915,
          "lng": -6.272516019708497
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.3335245197085,
          "lng": -6.275213980291502
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJYVO9ECIMZ0gR2bQrf0Ktmso",
    "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "8PMG+WF Dublin, County Dublin, Ireland",
      "global_code": "9C5M8PMG+WF"
    },
    "types": [
      "street_address"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "18",
        "short_name": "18",
        "types": [
          "street_number"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Clanbrassil Street Lower",
        "short_name": "Clanbrassil Street Lower",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Wood Quay",
        "short_name": "Wood Quay",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "18 Clanbrassil Street Lower, Wood Quay, Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3349987,
        "lng": -6.2739341
      },
      "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.3363476802915,
          "lng": -6.272585119708499
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.3336497197085,
          "lng": -6.275283080291502
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "EiwxOCBDbGFuYnJhc3NpbCBTdHJlZXQgTG93ZXIsIER1YmxpbiwgSXJlbGFuZCIaEhgKFAoSCQexJhIiDGdIEUlWW2rVpRfqEBI",
    "types": [
      "street_address"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Clanbrassil Street Lower",
        "short_name": "R137",
        "types": [
          "route"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Merchants Quay",
        "short_name": "Merchants Quay",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Clanbrassil Street Lower, Merchants Quay, Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.33516729999999,
          "lng": -6.273907599999999
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.3345896,
          "lng": -6.274462
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3348778,
        "lng": -6.274183000000001
      },
      "location_type": "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.33622743029149,
          "lng": -6.272835819708497
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.33352946970849,
          "lng": -6.275533780291502
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJzSxnESIMZ0gR8A77SK0ccBQ",
    "types": [
      "route"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Wood Quay",
        "short_name": "Wood Quay",
        "types": [
          "neighborhood",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Wood Quay, Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.3454641,
          "lng": -6.2680769
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.329641,
          "lng": -6.275519999999999
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.33275459999999,
        "lng": -6.2706881
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.3454641,
          "lng": -6.2680769
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.329641,
          "lng": -6.275519999999999
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJl78TlSEMZ0gRUHtT8SkTqVA",
    "types": [
      "neighborhood",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin 8",
        "short_name": "Dublin 8",
        "types": [
          "postal_town"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Dublin 8, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.37132399999999,
          "lng": -6.2642699
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.325953,
          "lng": -6.3563488
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.34785249999999,
        "lng": -6.318115199999999
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.37132399999999,
          "lng": -6.2642699
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.325953,
          "lng": -6.3563488
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJLz14IT8MZ0gR2uKxYpAO0Bc",
    "types": [
      "postal_town"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin City",
        "short_name": "Dublin City",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_2",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Dublin City, Co. Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.4111566,
          "lng": -6.11309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.2988569,
          "lng": -6.387080600000001
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3603142,
        "lng": -6.315054200000001
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.4111566,
          "lng": -6.11309
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.2988569,
          "lng": -6.387080600000001
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJv2RI7foRZ0gRwAKA8azHAAM",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_2",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Dublin",
        "short_name": "Dublin",
        "types": [
          "locality",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.42521010000001,
          "lng": -6.0439235
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.22343009999999,
          "lng": -6.4474847
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3498053,
        "lng": -6.2603097
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.42521010000001,
          "lng": -6.0439235
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.22343009999999,
          "lng": -6.4474847
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJL6wn6oAOZ0gRoHExl6nHAAo",
    "types": [
      "locality",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "County Dublin",
        "short_name": "County Dublin",
        "types": [
          "administrative_area_level_1",
          "political"
        ]
      },
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Co. Dublin, Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.6347257,
          "lng": -5.9962748
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.1781971,
          "lng": -6.5468798
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.3302033,
        "lng": -6.3105655
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 53.6347257,
          "lng": -5.9962748
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 53.1781971,
          "lng": -6.5468798
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJv2RI7foRZ0gRwAKA8azHABg",
    "types": [
      "administrative_area_level_1",
      "political"
    ]
  },
  {
    "address_components": [
      {
        "long_name": "Ireland",
        "short_name": "IE",
        "types": [
          "country",
          "political"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "formatted_address": "Ireland",
    "geometry": {
      "bounds": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 55.4602,
          "lng": -5.668900100000001
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 51.3066,
          "lng": -10.7666001
        }
      },
      "location": {
        "lat": 53.41291,
        "lng": -8.24389
      },
      "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
      "viewport": {
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 55.4602,
          "lng": -5.668900100000001
        },
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 51.3066,
          "lng": -10.7666001
        }
      }
    },
    "place_id": "ChIJ-ydAXOS6WUgRCPTbzjQSfM8",
    "types": [
      "country",
      "political"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Post the proper object, not copied from console.log

Comment: What do you mean by that, where else can I copy it from?

Comment: You can do something like this and post a valid JS data [copy from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305365/javascript-chrome-how-to-copy-an-object-from-the-webkit-inspector-as-code)

Comment: So either 'locality' or 'political' in the types array, should be a match right?

Comment: @godof23 I'm trying to get a match if both are in the types array. Though I wouldn't mind having a code that matches if either are in the types array either since that might come in handy later.

Comment: @Bobimaru you can use `find` along with `every` for both to match and `some` for atleast one,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the element that includes every of the mentioned types:

```
 array.find(it => ['locality', 'political'].every(type => it.types.includes(type)))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to alter this code so that locality and political are mandatory whilst having an option to add a third optional element to the array like 'country"?

Comment: @bobimaru yes it is :)

Comment: Is it lengthy change? I tried changing every() to some(), however, this way the code matches the first element which has either of the 3 values but I need to match at least 2.

Comment: Something else to consider: what happens when multiple objects satisfy your conditions (or does it even matter?)

Comment: @bobimaru you mean 2 out of 3? Thats another question btw

Answer (score 1):

So, let's examine what's going on here.

**Problem:** you have a array of objects, and you need to find and return the one that has the correct `types` array.

Well, first, we'll need to somehow examine each of the objects in the array — a for loop will work well for this. Specifically, we can use the `for(... of ...)` pattern:

```js
for(let object of array){
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Next, we'll need to test each of these objects based on the conditions we've set. We know we'll need to examine each object's `types` property, so we'll start there:

```js
for(let object of array){
    if(someKindOfTest(object.types)){
        return object;
    }
}
```

So how do we actually perform this test? Assuming we know what types we're looking for...

```js
let requiredTypes = ["locality"];

for(let object of array){
    if(someKindOfTest(object.types)){
        return object;
    }
}
```

...we can devise a test that only passes if the object has every one of the required types. Sounds like a job for another loop:

```js
let requiredTypes = ["locality"];

for(let object of array){
    let hasAllRequiredTypes = true;

    //  test for each of the required types

    for(let requiredType of requiredTypes){
        if(!object.types.includes(requiredType)){
            // this object doesn't match one of our required types, that disqualifies it

            hasAllTypes = false; // flag this object as disqualified
            break; // end this loop over the required types
        }
    }

    if(hasAllRequiredTypes) return object;
}
```

All of this can be compacted into a shorter, more "functional" version (@jonas-wilms answer is a great example of this), but I thought it useful to outline the underlying mechanisms and problem solving that would go into devising an algorithm like this.