# Append (key value) data to existing data in localstorage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to compare two id's and append a property into existing local storage data.
in for loop.

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Hamendra/pen/xxVKyXy?editors=0010)
that shows the sample data & logic.

Simply I am trying to check
the `id` of  `var allcategorydatawithlevel` with `categorydata` of `var category_id`
& if these two match I want to append
level property of the `allcategorydatawithlevel` to `categorydata`.
Please take a look at the Codepen it contains data sample & logic which I have tried.

Comment: Your objects (or array with objects) seem to copied and pasted from the console and therefore they are syntactically incorrect. Please fix your code and make it run without errors.

Comment: Ok, is their any way to fix that ?

Comment: There is. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305365/javascript-chrome-how-to-copy-an-object-from-the-webkit-inspector-as-code) on how to copy an object from the console in chrome.

Comment: Thankyou i have updated codepen

Comment: Please check the codepen

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you :

```
  var categorydata = [
        { category_id: 2, name: "Default Category", position: 1 },
        { category_id: 3, name: "Clothing", position: 14597 },
        { category_id: 6, name: "Brands", position: 1 },
        { category_id: 8, name: "What's New", position: 1011 },
        { category_id: 12, name: "Dresses", position: 4456 },
        { category_id: 128, name: "Current Mood", position: 189 },
        { category_id: 138, name: "Mini", position: 13078 },
        { category_id: 630, name: "Kandi - Rave Clothing", position: 264 },
        { category_id: 1130, name: "Char Test Category", position: 99 },
        { category_id: 2443, name: "Sets", position: 163 },
        { category_id: 2657, name: "Club Exx Festival", position: 208 }
    
    ];
    var allcategorydatawithlevel = [
        { id: 1, level: 1 },
        { id: 2, level: 5 }
    ]

  var category = [];
    
    for (i = 0; i < allcategorydatawithlevel.length; i++) {
        for (x = 0; x < categorydata.length; x++) {
            if (allcategorydatawithlevel[i].id == categorydata[x].category_id) {
                category.push(allcategorydatawithlevel[i].level);
            }
        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(category));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(category));
```

You can also use below code  :

```
  allcategorydatawithlevel.forEach((item, index) => {
        categorydata.forEach((key, val) => {
            if (item.id === key.category_id) {
                category.push(item.level);
            }
        })
        localStorage.setItem("category", JSON.stringify(category));

    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(category));
```

Comment: Let me check the above answer for the question.