# Getting the values of all the CSS properties of a selected element in Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, css, selenium, xpath

Suppose that I have found an element by its XPath using:

`WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some XPath"));`

I know that I can get the value of a particular CSS property by `we.getCssValue("some property")`, but can I get the values of all the properties without having to mention their names explicitly?

Comment: There is similar questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: actually it's only remotely similar, because @Milad wants to know how to do this within Selenium

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Unfortunately

this is not possible with native Selenium API.

## But using Javascript you can:

You can use some javascript support, using Seleniums' `JavascriptExecutor.executeScript` functionality.

The necessary js code can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011387/1943133) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)(as proposed by @Mahsum Akbas)

Now here is the Java/Selenium Code that will return you a string in the form of "css-attribute01:value01; css-attribute02:value02;".
Be aware that this will return **ALL** css-attributes on the element.

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String script = "var s = '';" +
                "var o = getComputedStyle(arguments[0]);" +
                "for(var i = 0; i < o.length; i++){" +
                "s+=o[i] + ':' + o.getPropertyValue(o[i])+';';}" + 
                "return s;";

System.out.println(executor.executeScript(script, we));
```

You can change the script according to your needs. For example you could return a string that ONLY has all the values without the attributes. Feel free to change and experiment.

## Update

If you would be interested in only the inline-styles of the element, then you can use "native" Selenium as pointed out by @JeffC in the comments:

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("style")
```

## BUT!:

This will give you only the "inline styles" and NOT all the css-styles that are applied to an element. If you run both versions after one another and print the results you will see the immense difference.

Comment: Well technically you can by using `driver.findElement(By.tagName("div")).getAttribute("style")` then you have to parse the individual properties like you did.

Comment: @JeffC with getAttribute("style") you will only get the elements inline styles, not ALL css-styles that are applied on the element! But it's a good point to complement my answer. thx.

Comment: @ShubhamJain haha, thx mate! brought me 1k xp ;-) rly special!

Answer (score 8):

Python version of using the above script to get all of the computed style properties:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pprint import pprint
#require geckodriver in the directory where this script runs
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

#Set the element object to the inbox messages icon
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@title="Recent inbox messages"]')

#Get all of the style properties for this element into a dictionary
styleprops_dict = driver.execute_script('var items = {};'+
                                   'var compsty = getComputedStyle(arguments[0]);'+
                                    'var len = compsty.length;'+
                                    'for (index = 0; index < len; index++)'+
                                    '{items [compsty[index]] = compsty.getPropertyValue(compsty[index])};'+
                                    'return items;', element)
pprint(styleprops_dict)
```