# Finding color of the text in selenium

Tags: selenium

Below is the code, trying to find the colour of the text 'Special Assistance' in spicejet.com. I am expecting rgb value as (196,18,48) (as shown in the developer view during inspection of the element)
however when i run the program it displays value as rgba (0,0,0,1);

```
    driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Special Assistance']"));
    System.out.println(ele.getCssValue("color"));
```

please help

Comment: You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537339/getting-the-values-of-all-the-css-properties-of-a-selected-element-in-selenium) useful.

Comment: Weird. I get three values when I try the same thing: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(196, 18, 48, 1) and
rgba(60, 60, 60, 1). I'm not using Java though, could println truncate it after the first line instead of outputting all the responses?

Comment: Please consider ticking as correct the answer which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

That page looks like it has multiple elements that match that xpath. As such I think you're getting the wrong one returned and the color is actually correct.

If you're actually looking for the red special assistance link this might be a better (more specific) xpath:

```
//*[@id='discount-checkbox']//a[text()='Special Assistance']
```

Try that, and I think you may find the expected results.

Comment: yes , you are right.. there were 3 elements with the first xpath i used, .. thank you

Comment: IF that fixed your problem then please select this answer as the correct answer. Thank you.