# Selenium C#: How to identify visible or invisible (style="...; display:none") which may be scrolled out of visible area

Tags: c#, css, selenium

we have automated a test, where table columns have been set to hidden (style="...; display:none").

Currently we are using *IWebElement.Displayed*.

This works fine if the whole table is visible (no scrollbar) but if some columns are scrolled out this don't work.
Is there a way to check it without checking the style attribute and without scrolling?

If I would need to use scrolling: how can I check for really invisible columns.

Thank you

Comment: Execute javascript to compute the effective style? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32537339/getting-the-values-of-all-the-css-properties-of-a-selected-element-in-selenium

Comment: Have you tried `element.GetAttribute("style")` or `element.GetProperty("style")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element attribute value with `GetAttribute()` method.

```cs
var style = IWebElement.GetAttribute("style");
```

Then you will be able to check if `style` string contains `display:none` etc.

Comment: I made it this way. But I hoped for something more independent from implementation.

Comment: What do you mean? Mode independent from what implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Get element location -

```
var e = your web element
var elementPosition = new Rectangle(e.Location, e.Size);
```

Get current screen position

```
var clientAreaRectangle = new Rectangle(GetScrollOffset(driver), driver.Manage().Window.Size)

public static Point GetScrollOffset(this IWebDriver driver)
{
    var executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    var offset = (Dictionary<string, object>)executor
        .ExecuteScript("return { X: Math.floor(window.pageXOffset), Y: Math.floor(window.pageYOffset) };");
    var offsetX = (int)(long)offset["X"];
    var offsetY = (int)(long)offset["Y"];
    return new(offsetX, offsetY);
}
```

Check if the element is scrolled into view

```
clientAreaRectangle.Contains(elementPosition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Irespective of the desired elements being ***visible*** / ***invisible*** i.e. with [`style="display: none;"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62075070/7429447), you can select all the table columns using the following [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

```
IList<IWebElement> Columns = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("XPathColumnElements"));
```

You can also induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57554488/7429447) for the [`PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy.htm) as follows:

```
IList<IWebElement> Columns = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.CssSelector("CssSelectorColumnElements")));
```