# Print html page with internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, printing

I have to print a table with its style
So I'm using jQuery.copyCSS to clone its CSS,style into another element
(Because I'm testing it on IE 8 and seems like it doesn't preserve CSS after clicking/calling window.print())
https://github.com/moagrius/copycss

I thought to "send" the table to another page and call from there the print.

Thus I need to clone the css into another element (to pass on the second page)

```
 $("#table_report").clone().attr({"id":"table_report_clone", "name":"clone"}).appendTo("body"); // doesn't matter if it appears on the page, I will just pass these one

    $('#table_report_clone').copyCSS('#table_report');  // copy CSS from original to clone

    var clone = $("#table_report_clone").html();

    var w = window.open();
    $(w.document.body).html(clone ); //table_report should be the table with its style
    w.document.close();
```

So, passing .html it will parse only the HTML not including the style

How can I do that?

**EDIT 1:**
Now some icons are being displayed..however the table is really 'raw'
w.document.write(clone); // instead of  $(w.document.body).html(clone);

**EDIT 2:**

Changed adding some tips by @Roljhon

En fact this does work on FF, Chrome, but in **IE 8 nope.**.
(Anyway I'm using JQuery 1.5.1)

**dumpCSSText** is a function from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15011387/7370271
since I have to get/join the styles attributes

```
        $("#table_report").inlineStyler();
        var table_report = document.getElementById("table_report");

        var w = window.open();
        var css = "" + dumpCSSText(table_report) //css of your table_content

        var style = document.createElement('style');

        style.type = "text/css";
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

        w.document.head.appendChild(style);
        w.document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById("table_report").innerHTML
```

**EDIT 3: Now it works**

var table_report = $("#table_report").html();

```
        var w = window.open();
        w.document.write('<html><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/css/apex.min.css?v=4.2.6.00.03" type="text/css" /><!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/css/apex_ie.min.css?v=4.2.6.00.03" type="text/css"/><![endif]--><link rel="stylesheet" href="/i/libraries/jquery-ui/1.8.22/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" /></head><body>');

        $(w.document.body).html(table_report);

        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.document.close();
        w.focus();
        w.print();
        w.close();
```

Finally I'm now at 90%..the only problem is CSS in IE8..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a solution to your problem and this could possibly solve it or give you an idea of what to do to pass your table css.

**Option 1**

You could create a link to the stylesheet.Create it directly from your javascript. But make sure that the stylesheet content is the exact CSS of the *table_content* and append this to the head section of the new window and at the same time write your *table* in the body part of the new window.

```
 var link = document.createElement('link');
 link.rel = "stylesheet";
 link.href ="table_content_style.css"; // this will have your table_content_clone CSS

 w.document.head.appendChild(link);
 w.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>"; // your html table markup
```

**Option 2**

You could create the stylesheet as well directly from javascript and doing the same thing as above.

```
 var css = "body{background-color: red;}"; //css of your table_content
 var style = document.createElement('style');
 style.type="text/css";
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));

 w.document.head.appendChild(style);
 w.document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>test</h1>"; // your html table markup
```

I hope that helps. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0vzwzrpq/

Comment: Thank you, it works on FF, Chrome..but in IE 8 nope
I'm using a function to get the style attributes from an element..
.inlineStyler() from https://github.com/davecranwell/inline-styler helps me to put everything inline

Comment: Hey mate, I tried to my best but I think this is an IE security feature which you can't move a DOM node to another document. But i'll try to find a workaround ,this kind of issue interest me a lot :D update the answer soon if found any!

Comment: Don't worry your tips helped me..now the problem is how can I put my table more on my left because in IE 8 there is a margin that put the table out of the page..
I've put my solution in EDIT 3, thank you

Comment: @MichaelJohnks IE bug I supposed. So you mean that IE is pushing your table to be more align on the left when you want it to be at the center? is that it?

Comment: Actually it puts the table more on right..like if there is a margin or something..this cut my table because it goes out of the page
I've put @Page { margin 0; } but nothing..

Comment: I hope this helps https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them--net-7764

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to style elements you'd like to print is to use CSS media queries.

```
@media print {
    body {
        background-color: pink;
    }
}
```

There is a very good article here about the subject: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: I'm testing it on IE 8 which doesn't support media queries
Not even using css3-mediaqueries-js..

Comment: use inline style rules instead. For IE8 and lower to center content you need <table align="center" style="margin:0 auto;"> (IE7 emulation does not recognise the auto margin rule.) then you can use jquery to clone the table (complete with the inline style rules) to the print preview window.