# Get all CSS rules for selected element in Google Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Google Chrome Dev Tools you can right click an element in the page HTML and click to **Copy Element** which copies the elements HTML to your clipboard.

[image]

Is there a way to copy all CSS rules associated with that elements HTML?

Answer (score 29):

Add the Chrome extension ["CSS Used"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/css-used/cdopjfddjlonogibjahpnmjpoangjfff) to your browser. After the installation you get an additional tab "CSS used" at the right side of the screen. The extension is also available via [github](https://github.com/painty/CSS-Used-ChromeExt).

You might also try [SnappySnippet](https://github.com/kdzwinel/SnappySnippet) as an alternative.

Comment: The name and a brief description of the resource would be helpful. As of now, if the URL changes, your answer becomes worthless. With some basic info / keywords, it would at least be searchable.

Answer (score 4):

The Styles and Computed tabs in DOM Explorer show the CSS rules that apply to a selected element. Choose `Inspect element` and then open the `Computed` tab and there you will the list of all the CSS applied to particular element.

You can also check this link for [Export CSS for DOM elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754469/export-css-of-dom-elements)

For more information for your question for multiple browsers check this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296622/how-can-i-grab-all-css-styles-of-on-element). It might help you.